# Render Images from Formula - Not Image address

Tags: formula, formula-field, image-formula

This formula is doing everything that I want except showing the actual Image on the field.  Instead it shows the image address.

[image: Image field]

```
IF( AND(ISPICKVAL(Asset.LBS__c, 'Active'),ISPICKVAL(Asset.Swap__c, 'Standard')), 'https://customdomain--sandbox.sandbox.file.force.com/servlet/servlet.FileDownload?file=0150w000000NPwK',

IF(ISPICKVAL(Asset.LBS__c, 'Active'), 'https://customdomain--sandbox.sandbox.file.force.com/servlet/servlet.FileDownload?file=0150w000000NPwA',

IF(ISPICKVAL(Asset.Swap__c, 'Standard'), 'https://customdomain--sandbox.sandbox.file.force.com/servlet/servlet.FileDownload?file=0150w000000NPwF', '')))
```

I was going to append the image addresses with **"Error',90,40),'')** but it wont pass the syntax check.

```
'https://customdomain--sandbox.sandbox.file.force.com/servlet/servlet.FileDownload?file=0150w000000NPwA','Error', 90,40),'')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using a string, not a formula, so you can't just add that on.

Instead, try this:

```
IMAGE(
    IF( 
        AND(
            ISPICKVAL(Asset.LBS__c, 'Active'),
            ISPICKVAL(Asset.Swap__c, 'Standard')
        ), 
        'https://customdomain--sandbox.sandbox.file.force.com/servlet/servlet.FileDownload?file=0150w000000NPwK',
        IF(
            ISPICKVAL(Asset.LBS__c, 'Active'), 
            'https://customdomain--sandbox.sandbox.file.force.com/servlet/servlet.FileDownload?file=0150w000000NPwA',
            IF(
                ISPICKVAL(Asset.Swap__c, 'Standard'), 
                'https://customdomain--sandbox.sandbox.file.force.com/servlet/servlet.FileDownload?file=0150w000000NPwF', 
                ''
            )
        )
    ), 
    'Error', 
    90, 
    40
)
```

Comment: Champion of Champions!

Comment: I notice that if the the formula doesn't contain any of the values the image field contains a corrupted image and the word error.  Do I need to do something to the end of the formula.  Ideally i'd like it to be blank if it doent meet the criteria.

Comment: @QuangoBruce You will probably want to add a check at the beginning: `IF(            ISPICKVAL(Asset.LBS__c, 'Active') || ISPICKVAL(Asset.Swap__c, 'Standard'), ..., NULL)` if you want to not emit an image if none of the situations apply.

Comment: Hi - Still getting errors - Have I put this in the right place: `IF( (ISPICKVAL( LDS__c, 'Active') || ISPICKVAL(Swap__c, 'Standard') , 'mydomain--sandbox.sandbox.file.force.com/servlet/…), IF( ISPICKVAL(LDS__c, 'Active'), 'mydomain--sandbox.sandbox.file.force.com/servlet/…', IF( ISPICKVAL(Swap__c, 'Standard'), 'mydomian--sandbox.sandbox.file.force.com/servlet/…', '' ) ) ) , "Error", 60, 90 )`

Comment: @QuangoBruce `(ISPICKVAL( LDS__c, 'Active') || ISPICKVAL(Swap__c, 'Standard') ,'mydomain--sandbox.sandbox.file.force.com/servlet/…)` the parentheses at the very beginning and very end should not be there. In addition, you forgot the IMAGE part.

Comment: @QuangoBruce try: `IMAGE(IF( ISPICKVAL( LDS__c, 'Active') || ISPICKVAL(Swap__c, 'Standard') ,'mydomain--sandbox.sandbox.file.force.com/servlet/…',IF( ISPICKVAL(LDS__c, 'Active'),'mydomain--sandbox.sandbox.file.force.com/servlet/…',IF( ISPICKVAL(Swap__c, 'Standard'),'mydomian--sandbox.sandbox.file.force.com/servlet/…',''))) , "Error", 60, 90 )`